# VMWare - Guest cant ping Host and vice versa

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I am unable to connect to my host from the virtual machine and vice versa.
I researched many hours but I am still unable to locate the problem.

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.178.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.178.255
gateway 192.168.178.1
```

I also tried `iface eth0 inet dhcp` and restarted the network after it with `service networking restart`. But if I try to ping the host or the router, then I always get `Destination host unreachable`.

**ifconfig output snippet:**

```
eth0    Link encap: Ethernet
        Hardware Addresse 00:50:XX:XX:XX:XX
        inet Adresse: 192.168.178.150  
        Bcast: 192.168.178.255
        Maske: 255.255.255.0
```

**VMWare settings:**

[image: settings]

What else did I try:

- disabled the `network-manager`: makes no difference.
- entering `nameserver 192.168.178.1` to `/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check iptables on guest os (Linux as per your explanation), it might be blocking ping requests. To list the iptables firewall config type:

iptables -nL

if iptables Returns Nothing Make Sure the 'VMware Virtual Network' driver is properly installed and functional on the host os.

Consider taking a backup of your guest VM and reinstalling VMware.

Good Luck Buddy!

Comment: `iptables -nL` returned no rules so I selected "repair" on the deinstallation menu of VM Ware, it deinstalled the Virtual Network Devices and installed some new ones. Now it is working! THX! :)